# VBA: Table Boundaries and Overflow Error 6

Tags: excel, stack-overflow, do-loops, vba

I am trying to get the table boundaries of an excel sheet using VBA.  I have already done this using C#, but now I need to try and translate that code to VBA.

One problem is that the syntax seems to be so different that the code does not look even similar, even or that it is simply doing the same thing! I think I am pretty close to figuring out the dimensions of a table but I'm getting this `Run-time error '6': Overflow` message.

Here's the code:

```
Dim currentRow As Integer
Dim totalRow As Integer
Dim column As Integer

currentRow = 2

Do
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
totalRow = totalRow + 1
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)) = False
```

The error occurs once it is close to being done with the `Do loop`.  I read another forum response that was saying VB is slow, and that a potential error is that the `Do loop` is going too fast and thus getting an overflow.  If that is the case, I am entirely unsure of how to solve it.

Does anyone have a way to fix the overflow problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the .End method of Range instead of looping to find the first empty cell.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize they had a whole method to do that.  Thanks!  I was trying to assign totalRow to Range("A1").End(x1Down).Select but when I put it through the debugger x1Down is equal to -4121 and totalRow gets -1.  I don't understand these values because the excel sheet that I'm using right now has 1095 rows (1094 if you exclude the header row).  Am I using the method incorrectly?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the Range("A1").End*x1Down).Select part seems to work, as I go through the debugger and I hit that line my Excel sheet jumps down to the correct row (1095)

Comment: It's "xlDown" not "x1Down". That is just a predefined constant which is used to tell the End method that what you want to do is find the last cell. You might want `totalRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row`

Comment: *gasp* it worked! i was prepared to do much more drastic, and a little bit longer, bits of code!  awesome, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You might like to look at UsedRange. Try

```
 Dim totalRow As Long
```

UsedRange: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange(VS.80).aspx
Data type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164754(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I think I was running into some sort of infinite loop because when I switched totalRow to Long and ran it my Excel and VBA code both stopped working haha.  That probably means that my code was reading the null cells and just shrugging it off and moving on.  Thank you for helping - Jesse

Comment: @Jesse Smothermon I was really trying to draw your attention to UsedRange, with an aside on why you got the error.